# Android lags/stalls when running the HTTP post/get methods

Tags: android, http, post, lag

So I have a successful application with a form that registers a user with my website, and I created a 15 frame png animation that also runs well on command.

I have the animation starts up (and is looping) first and then run the HTTP POST at the end of the animation. When the HTTP Post is doing its thing, the animation (pretty much all of android) lags or pauses and then will continue to function after the POST is done.

Is this normal? Is there a way to make it not lag when running the POST?

Thanks!

And for those who are curious, here's my httpClass (mywebsite.com is just a prop for my actual URL)

```
try{

                Log.d("MYTAG", "Registration begin"); 
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String postURL = "mywebsite.com";
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fullName", fullName));
                UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
                post.setEntity(ent);
                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
                if(resEntity!=null){
                    newCode = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                } else {
                    newCode = (String) null;
                }
             }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("MYTAG", "Exception e="+e);
             }
             return newCode;
    }
```

Comment: Is this work occurring on your Activity's UI thread? If so, that would explain why the app is stalling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix that up with an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  Google has an introduction to it [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).  It won't make things go faster but it will keep your UI thread from stalling out.

Comment: The AsyncTask will allow you to display an "in progress" dialog so your users know the app is processing data and you won't get that "close app or wait" dialog.

Comment: I just read up the AsyncTask, it looks like this is a better option to go with.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, my guess at your problem would be that you're executing this code on the main thread which is interfering with the drawing of the animation. To be more help, I think we'd need to see more of the Activity. For these sorts of issues, we'd have to know the threads you are using and how you are moving your net code off your main application thread.

Comment: Well the activity that has the forms and the SUBMIT button has a string that calls out to a httpClass.class. The class returns a string with what php echo's out.

Comment: So, this is a fairly complicated task to cover in a comment. You need to understand that the UI isn't threadsafe. So, there is only one thread that can modify the ui called your 'main' or 'application' thread. If you use that thread to do network stuff, it can't also update your ui, so your ui gets clunky and slow. You need to create a separate thread to do your network stuff. You can start by wrapping your call in a thread or by using the AsyncTask which @Haphaz pointed out. [Here is the FAQ from the dev guide about this.](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#threading)

Comment: this is excellent information! Would you recommend using the new thread procedure if I"m using custom UI graphics?  Why would I use this over AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code in it's own thread? If you aren't then it's lags/stops because the UI thread is being blocked.

Comment: no, not it's own class. check out android documentation on threading: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html